# how to get my string commands by getline() and stringstream

Tags: c++, getline, stringstream

I want to know whether I'm using the right form to get my command in a line and then by some `if`s get the info each command needs. This is a part of my code; actually, the first part of my `main` function:

```
string line;
stringstream ss;

while (!cin.eof())
{
    getline(cin, line);
    //i dont know if next line should be used   
    ss << line;
    if (line.size() == 0)
        continue;

    ss >> command;

    if (command == "put")
    {
         string your_file_ad, destin_ad;
         ss >> your_file_ad >> destin_ad;
         //baraye history ezafe shod
         give_file(your_file_ad, p_online)->index_plus(command);
```

Comment: related: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: I think you want to do some processing based on the value of command, and write the details each command has on a string stream, am i correct ?

Comment: yes based on what a command is im gonna get different information from the user ...

Comment: Who taught you to write `while (!cin.eof())`? That is _incorrect_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried to run your code with two additional `cout`s in your `if`, to see what happens when for example user enters `put a b`.

So, this is my code:

```
string line;
stringstream ss;
while (true)
{
    getline(cin, line);
    //i dont know if next line should be used   

    ss << line;
    if (line.size() == 0)
        continue;

    string command;
    ss >> command;

    if (command == "put")
    {
        string your_file_ad, destin_ad;
        ss >> your_file_ad >> destin_ad;
        cout << "input #1 is " << your_file_ad << endl;
        cout << "input #2 is " << destin_ad << endl;
    }
}
```

When I run this code, then if I write `put a b` in the console, I'll see this result, which is correct:

```
input #1 is a
input #2 is b
```

But it seems that this **only** works for the first command. after that commands couldn't process correctly.

So, I read the code again, and found out that the problem is, you are initializing your `stringstream` outside of the while.

I'm not sure why exactly it doesn't work (maybe already reached EOF and can't continue reading anymore?), but if you move `stringstream ss;` inside the while, it'll work correctly:

```
string line;
while (true)
{
    stringstream ss;

    getline(cin, line);
    //i dont know if next line should be used   

    ss << line;
    if (line.size() == 0)
        continue;

    string command;
    ss >> command;

    if (command == "put")
    {
        string your_file_ad, destin_ad;
        ss >> your_file_ad >> destin_ad;
        cout << "input #1 is " << your_file_ad << endl;
        cout << "input #2 is " << destin_ad << endl;
    }
}
```

[image]

*Update:* read @LightnessRacesinOrbit comment below about the issue with the first code.

Comment: No, you are also using `while (!cin.eof())`. Stop doing that immediately!!! Let me know when you have fixed this bug so I can remove my downvote.

Comment: And, yes, the problem is the EOF bit being set on the stringstream. You can re-use it if you reset its content and flags, but instead making it scope-bound works too.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That is not related to what the question wants, but I'll replace it with a simple `while (true)` anyway :) asker can change it to whatever is necessary based on what he wants. Also, thanks for your comment about EOF. I'll update the answer with more details.

Comment: The OP wants code that works, and advice that is correct. Your answer does not satisfy those criteria as long as you are spreading this misconceptive `while (!cin.eof())` nonsense. Changing it to `while (true)` _does not fix the problem_. It actually shows that right there in your screengrab: one additional loop iteration that you don't want. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong), carefully. Then read it again. Then phone up the person who taught you to write `while (!cin.eof())`, and tell _them_ to read it.